# How can I add an addin in visual studio 2008 by menu item

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

I want to write some addin in vs2008 to help me do some repetitive work. And I want to see my addin in the menu item when I right click my class name in editor. And who can tell me hwo to add my addin in the menu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [Adding buttons, commandbars and toolbars to Visual Studio .NET from an add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005003.aspx) for detailed explanation. Basically you need to call **Commands.AddNamedCommand** to create your command and then call **myCommand.AddControl(CommandBars["Code Window"])**.